# Merge duplicate row in csv based on firts column key

Tags: python, pandas

I try to merge 3 csv with different structure but common fields.
I'm using panda to do it.

I've got 3 csv like that :

**csv1**

```
sku;col1;col2;test
123;456;99;A
234;786;99;
345;678;99;A
```

**csv2**

```
sku;col3;col4;test
123;18-123;9999;A
234;18-786;9999;
345;12-678;9999;A
```

**csv3**

```
sku;col5;col6;test
123;18-123;9999;
234;18-786;9999;A
345;12-678;9999;
```

my script is like that :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from functools import reduce

a = pd.read_csv("csv1.csv",sep =';', low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("csv2.csv",sep =';', low_memory=False)

a = a.astype('object')
b = b.astype('object')

val = np.intersect1d(a.columns, b.columns).tolist()
merged = a.merge(b, on=val, how='outer')
merged.to_csv("csv1_2.csv",sep=';', index=False)

c = pd.read_csv("csv1_2.csv",sep =';', low_memory=False)
c = c.astype('object')
d = pd.read_csv("csv3.csv",sep =';', low_memory=False)
d = d.astype('object')

val = np.intersect1d(c.columns, d.columns).tolist()
merged = c.merge(d, on=val, how='outer')
merged.to_csv("csv1_2_3.csv",sep=';', index=False)
```

it's woking as I get a merged csv like that :

```
sku;col1;col2;test;col3;col4;col5;col6
123;456;99;A;18-123;9999;;
234;786;99;A;18-786;9999;18-786;9999
345;678;99;A;12-678;9999;;
123;;;;;;18-123;9999
345;;;;;;12-678;9999
```

but there is "duplicate row" and i want to "merge" row with the same sku to get a final csv like that

```
sku;col1;col2;test;col3;col4;col5;col6
123;456;99;A;18-123;9999;18-123;9999
234;786;99;A;18-786;9999;18-786;9999
345;678;99;A;12-678;9999;12-678;9999
```

Do you have any hint on what to do next to "merge" row by sku ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `pd.concat()`

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(x, sep=';', index_col='sku')
   ...:            for x in ['csv1', 'csv2', 'csv3']], axis=1)

df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]

     col1  col2 test    col3  col4    col5  col6
sku                                             
123   456    99    A  18-123  9999  18-123  9999
234   786    99    A  18-786  9999  18-786  9999
345   678    99    A  12-678  9999  12-678  9999
```

Comment: I might do something wrong cause i "loose" some data.
if a value is on one csv and not in the other one the field is not filled.

for example on my example the test colum only got a value in csv file 3 for sku 234 but in my final output I only got a value for sku 123 and 345.

Thanks